Dataset of bacterial growth according to time from an experiment with\without antibiotics
I'm looking for a dataset about the growth of a bacteria according to time if possible the name of the bacteria and the condition (the protocol). Also if possible I would like to have this sort of data with an antibiotic (bactericidal or/and bacteriostatic) with the name of it. I would like to compare a model to the actual data to confirm the validity of it. Thank you for reading and your time, best regard.
